# Why i couldn't connect redis cli from local?

Tags: docker, redis, containers, redis-cli

I'm trying to connect redis-cli, but i can't. what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Redis server is running in the container.
The Redis image contains redis-cli binary.

You can connect the `redis-cli` binary in the running container if you're just hacking around stuff.

```sh
docker exec -it `docker ps --filter 'ancestor=redis' --filter 'status=running' --format '{{.ID}}'` redis-cli
```

Otherwise, follow through with the recommendation to install `redis-tools`.